# includePath in VSCode w/ MSYS2

Tags: visual-studio-code, msys2

Try as I might, I simply cannot get VSCode to find ANY headers I've specified in includePath and browse->path. Here is my c_cpp_properties.json file. Surely VSCode should be able to find curses.h after this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "MSYS2",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/ncurses/"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/ncurses/"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I've tried forward and backslashes in the pathnames. Nothing seems to work. I should mention that I'm using MSYS2/MinGW-w64.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in my own default 'c_cpp_properties.json' file that all path strings were using a **double backslash**.

```
"C:\\So\\Something\\Like\\This.exe"
```